# Snapshot contains values but "posts" variable does not

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, viewcontroller

Still haven't figured out!...I am trying to show data from Firebase but my "posts" variable does not contain values although snapshot contains 3 values. I think something is wrong with my "let posts = snapshot.flatMap(Post.init)".

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var posts = [Post]()

    var userPostHandle: DatabaseHandle = 0
    var userPostRef: DatabaseReference?

    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...

        // 2
        userPostsHandle = UserService.observePosts { [weak self] (ref, posts) in
            self?.userPostsRef = ref
            self?.posts = posts

            // 3
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        // 4
        userPostsRef?.removeObserver(withHandle: userPostsHandle)
    }
}
```

(The function from User Service called observePosts - posts has 0 values although snapshot had values when I tested earlier)

```
static func observePosts(for user: User = User.current, withCompletion completion: @escaping (DatabaseReference, [Post]) -> Void) -> DatabaseHandle {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(user.username)

    return ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let posts = Post(snapshot: snapshot) else {
            return completion(ref, [])
        }
        let posts = snapshot.flatMap(Post.init)
        completion(ref, posts)
    })
}
```

Comment: Did you assigned datasource & delegate to tableview

Comment: Addition to @Dimple query, did you print `posts` `count` i.e, `print(posts.count)`?

Comment: No would I print that to check for something?

Comment: Did you set the data source correctly to `ViewBetsViewController` class? looks like you have two classes.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to assign datasource & delegate to your `tableView`.
You can do it by programatically or from storyboard. Please check below for programatically.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.rowHeight = 71
    // remove separators for empty cells
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    // 2
    userPostsHandle = UserService.observePosts { [weak self] (ref, posts) in
        self?.userPostsRef = ref
        self?.posts = posts

        // 3
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.datasource = self
}
```

Comment: Yes I have :(( so not sure what else could be going wrong.

Comment: His first ViewController is not implementing `UITableViewDataSource` or `UITableViewDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. You can assign ref in the async.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.datasource = self

    tableView.rowHeight = 71
    // remove separators for empty cells
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    // 2
    userPostsHandle = UserService.observePosts { [weak self] (ref, posts) in

        // 3
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.userPostsRef = ref
            self?.posts = posts
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you append this code block to your question. Its hard to read from this

Comment: Yes i added recently

Comment: could you plase add your cellforrowat block